# select all values after specific value until next specific values in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a normal array which has a lot of data in it. Let's say the array is structured like this:

```
$myArray = array( 'a','b','c','title1','d','e','f','title2','g','h','title3','i','title4','j','k' );
```

I need to extract this values and put all values after title() value until next title() value in one array. Something like this:

```
$newarray[0] = array('a','b','c');
$newarray[1] = array('d','e','f');
$newarray[2] = array('g','h');
$newarray[3] = array('i');
$newarray[4] = array('j','k');
```

@mickmackusa answer worked correctly but i need use title() for batch key something like this:

```
$newarray[0] = array('a','b','c');
$newarray[title1] = array('d','e','f');
$newarray[title2] = array('g','h');
$newarray[title3] = array('i');
$newarray[title4] = array('j','k');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perform iterated checks for a string that starts with `title`.  That indicates the break point between batches.  When you store a batch, reset the batch for the next iteration.  When the loop is finished, check for a final / not-yet-stored batch.

Code #1: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/nX9oe))

```
$myArray = array( 'a','b','c','title1','d','e','f','title2','g','h','title3','i','title4','j','k' );
foreach ($myArray as $v) {
    if (strpos($v, 'title') !== 0) {
        $batch[] = $v;
    } elseif (!empty($batch)) {
        $result[] = $batch;
        $batch = [];
    }
}
if (!empty($batch)) {
    $result[] = $batch;
}

var_export($result);
```

Or use explicit keys for each batch subarray.

Code #2: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/usHMt))

```
$batch = 0;                          // set first batch key
foreach ($myArray as $v) {
    if (strpos($v, 'title') !== 0) {
        $result[$batch][] = $v;      // use explicit batch key
    } else {
        ++$batch;                    // increment batch key
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

Output: (both snippets generate the same)

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 'a',
    1 => 'b',
    2 => 'c',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 'd',
    1 => 'e',
    2 => 'f',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 'g',
    1 => 'h',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    0 => 'i',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    0 => 'j',
    1 => 'k',
  ),
)
```

---

After Question Update:

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/lZAIm))

```
$batch = 0;                           // default value
foreach ($myArray as $v) {
    if (strpos($v, 'title') !== 0) {  // value is NOT a "title#"" string
        $result[$batch][] = $v;       // save with current batch value as 1st level key 
    } else {
        $batch = $v;                  // update batch value with "title#" string
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

Comment: tnx it's worked. I in need use title(#) as batch key. How can i do this? (edited question)

Answer (score 0):

Try this , but you have to optimize it

```
    $myArray = array( 'a','b','c','title1','d','e','f','title2','g','h','title3','i','title4','j','k' );

    $newArray=[];


    $ind=0;

    for($i=0;$i<count($myArray);$i++){

        if(preg_match("/title/",$myArray[$i])==1){
            $ind++;
        }else{
            $newArray[$ind][]=$myArray[$i];
        }
    }

    var_dump($newArray);
```

Comment: Please avoid posting _Try this_ / code-only answers.  They are low-value on StackOverflow because they do a poor job of educating the OP and thousands of future researchers.  Always explain how your code works and why it is a good idea.  Always.

Comment: p.s. a `preg_` function is not necessary and is overkill.